# Identifying the source of "TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type text..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error on my React project when I navigate from one route to another:

> Warning: TextField is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

It is a big project. How do I found the source for it?

The stack trace is not helpful:
[image: stack trace react]
It goes on and on without any non-react code.

Comment: Trying to get some context... is TextField a custom react component you've created?  There may be an onchange event on that that mutates something else?  I've never seen this error. I'm intrigued.

Comment: Does this error come up on any specific action on the page? Or on page load? You can use the React chrome dev tools plugin to see which components are loaded into the page when this error pops up

Comment: Using React chrome dev tools I looked for the TextFields on page. Interesting, apparently the problem is not with the page I load, it's with the page I leave. When I navigate to another route the error pops up so I guess it is related to a TextField which lives in the route I navigate away from.

Comment: Maybe I forgot cleaning something up?